# How to query using an Enum parameter mapped as ORDINAL using JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, hibernate-mapping

I need to get data from database by enum type.
I have following enum:

```
public enum ShopType {
    VANS("VANS"), ATTICUS("ATTICUS"), FAMOUS("FAMOUS")

    ShopType(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    private String label;

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

In my DAO class i have method which returns list of objects by selected type on `jsp` page. On `jsp` page i send selected value like `String`, is it right?

That how looks my method

```
@Transactional
public List<Shop> findByType(String type) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Shop where type=" + .....  .list();
}
```

I don't know how to create right query. Enum i store in my database like tinyint.

Here is a model.

```
@Column(name = "type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private ShopType type;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you set your enum as ordinal, then in query you should use ordinal. Example;

```
@Transactional
public List<Shop> findByType(String type) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Shop where type=" + ShopType.valueOf(type).ordinal()).list();
}
```

If you change `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, then your query will look like;

```
@Transactional
public List<Shop> findByType(String type) {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Shop where type=" + ShopType.valueOf(type).name()).list();
}
```

`ShopType.valueOf(type)`, This will work only if string type is same as enum name.
Also if your label is same as enum name, then you don't need label.
`ShopType.VANS.name()`is equals`"VANS"` and `name()` method is final, you can be sure that can't be overridden.

Comment: result should depends on type param which receives findByType method, you just hardcoded VANS type

Answer (score 6):

The problem in your query is that you concatenated the bind parameter value which, apart from causing your issue, may expose your application to [SQL injection attacks](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sql-injection-and-how-you-should-prevent-it/).

If you write the query using bind parameter values:

```
Post post = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select p " +
    "from Post p " +
    "where p.status = :status", Post.class)
.setParameter("status", PostStatus.PENDING)
.getSingleResult();

assertEquals("High-Performance Java Persistence", post.getTitle());
```

Hibernate will properly use the ORDINAL value in the SQL query:

```
Query:["
    select 
        p.id as id1_0_,
        p.status as status2_0_, 
        p.title as title3_0_ 
    from 
        post p 
    where 
        p.status=?
"], 
Params:[
    0
]
```

For a working example, check out the [`EnumOrdinalTest`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/f711551ab4b3631a2c85609d44cd243391d11cb6/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/mapping/enums/EnumOrdinalTest.java) in my [`high-performance-java-persistence` GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence).

Answer (score 4):

Just convert String to Enum and use named query parameter

```
@Transactional
public List<Shop> findByType(String type) {
    ShopType enumType = shopTypeFromString(type);
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Shop where type=:p_type")
        .setParameter("p_type", enumType).list();
}

private ShopType shopTypeFromString(String type) {
    // You can implement this convertion in your own way
    return ShopType.valueOf(type);
}
```

Comment: i'm guessing it's not nice=)